# Two point series on the same graph on MatLab

Tags: matlab

I want to draw two separated lines, but I get the two lines on two points. How do I draw them separated?

When you implement the code, the green line should start from point 3 and end in point 4 on the x-tick. But, it starts again from point 1 and end in point2.

```
%% My question code:
a=3; %point1
b=4; %point2
c=6; %point3
d=7; %point4
plot([a b], 'k- *');
hold on;
plot([c d], 'g- *');
hold off
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:4, 'XTickLabel', {'point1', 'point2', 'point3','point4'})
axis([0 10 0 10]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you **[`hold`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)** the current plot and [**`plot`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) a new one. `x` axis values are taken as if it is the first plot. To avoid the confusion, specify values for both x and y axes.

So change your `plot` commands like this:

```
plot([1,2], [a,b], 'k- *');
hold on;
plot([3,4], [c,d], 'g- *');
hold off;
```

or combine two `plot` commands into a single one like this:

```
plot([1,2], [a,b], 'k- *', [3,4], [c,d], 'g- *');
```

Comment: Thanks you Sardar.

Comment: @MariamSalehi No problem. Good luck!

Comment: Sure I did that. Thanks :-)